# Check if a popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

I am opening a popup window with

```
var popup = window.open('...', '...');
```

This javascript is defined in a control. This control is then used from a web page. I want to reload the page which opens this popup when the popup is closed.

Basically user is required to input some denominations in the popup window and submit. These denominations are then stored in user sessions. And when user clicks submit I am closing the popup window and at the same time want to refresh the window which opens this popup to refetch the updates which user made in the popup.

I am trying to do

```
var popup = window.open('...','...');
if (popup) {
  popup.onClose = function () { popup.opener.location.reload(); }
}
```

I guess I am doing it wrong coz this isn't seems to be working.

For testing the issue I've even tried this but no alert appeared.

```
if (popup) {
  popup.onclose = function() { 
    alert("1.InsideHandler");
    if (opener && !opener.closed) { 
      alert("2.Executed.");
      opener.location.reload(true); 
    } else { 
      alert("3.NotExecuted.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can You/Have you tried using a Modal Popup?

Comment: You do not want to submit a form in a modal window unless you submit it to an iFrame

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I suggest (updated to newer code)

in the popup you should have:

```js
const reloadOpener = () => {
  if (top.opener && !top.opener.closed) {
    try {
      opener.location.reload(1); 
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    window.close();
  }
}
window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
  reloadOpener();
})
```

```html
<form action="..." target="hiddenFrame">
</form>
<iframe style="width:10px; height:10px; display:none" name="hiddenFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

then **assuming the same origin**, the server process can return

```js
<script> top.close(); </script>
```

NOTE: `location.reload` takes a boolean, add true if you want to not load from cache
as in `opener.location.reload(1);`

Comment: The window gets reloaded immediately when a popup opens.

Comment: by the way it would be onclose, lowercase C. Not supported by all browsers

Comment: for testing I used this >>> popup.onClose = function() { if (opener && !opener.closed) { alert("Executed..."); opener.location.reload(); } }   But the alert never shows.

Comment: Change the onClose to onclose and make sure you use a browser that supports this

Comment: I've even tried this but no alert >>>> popup.onclose = function() { alert("1.InsideHandler"); if (opener && !opener.closed) { alert("2.Executed."); opener.location.reload(true); } else { alert("3.NotExecuted."); } }

Comment: This does not fail in Fx but does not execute the script in the popup. It DOES fail in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pxySQ/

Comment: Sorry man, I really don't know why I downvoted this. Maybe I was just tired and misclicked. I can't undo my vote unless the answer is edited. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

## Solution for same origin popups

If your popup is from the same origin as the opener, you can attach an event listener to the popup like this:

```
const popup = window.open('...', '...');

popup.window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    popup.window.addEventListener('unload', () => {
        console.log('> Popup Closed');
        // window.location.reload();
    });
});
```

Note that the unload event listener needs to be added once the popup is loaded. This is because the unload event also fires on page load in popups.

## Solutions for different origin popups

If your popup is not from the same origin as the opener, when you try to add the listeners, you will receive an error like this: `Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.` For security reasons, you can only access a limited set of properties from both opener and the opened window.
More about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_script_api_access).

### Solution 1

If you have access to the origin in the popup, you could create the unload event listener in your popup and call `window.opener.location.replace(OPENER_URL)`. The drawback of this is that you need the opener's URL. Instead of hardcoding, you could pass the OPENER_URL as a query string to the popup.

Note that `window.opener.location.reload()` is not allowed in a cross-origin scenario, so you have to use `.replace(OPENER_URL)`

### Solution 2

You could simply create an interval in the opener to periodically check whether the window is open or not with the [window.closed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed) property.

```
const popup = window.open('...', '...');

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (popup.closed) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('> Popup Closed');
        // window.location.reload();
    }
}, 500);
```

This is probably the most flexible solution. It is also used by the PayPal API for payment popups (with a polyfill for the closed property)

Comment: Solution 2 works so well

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

or

Into the popup before closing

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should use a modal dialog like so

```
var popup = window.showModalDialog("page.html", "", params);
```

This would stop your at this line until the dialog is closed.

Somewhere in your page.html you would then code some javascript to set the `window.returnValue` which is what will be place the the popup variable.

**Update**

Window.showModalDialog() is [now obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog).

Comment: Except it is tricky to submit a form in a modal window unless it has an iframe to submit to

Comment: And whats to stop them placing it in an iframe?

Comment: requirement is to use a modless

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what you do is as follows.

create a method "setWindowObjectInParent" then call that in the popup.
var popupwindow;

```
function setWindowObjectInParent(obj)
{
popupwindow = obj;
}
```

Now you have an object that you can call focus on.

So in the popup add

```
$(window).unload(function(){
window.opener.setWindowObjectInParent();
});
window.opener.setWindowObjectInParent(window);
```

This will unset the obj when the popup is closed and set the object when it is opened.

Thus you can check if your popup is defined and then call focus.