# How to close a popup window after sending ajax request to rails controller without reloading parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, popup

I am in show view of a controller and if a user clicks on a link, a popup window with a form is displayed. If the user clicks "Submit", the form is submitted via ajax to a custom "action" in the same controller. In the action.js.erb partial I have the following code:

```
  window.opener.location.reload();
  window.close();
```

It works fine, but the whole show view page is reloaded. And I'd like just to have the focus back and write some div updates in the js.erb partial.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery to hide it once completed.

```
$('#popup_wrapper_id').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling from helper , close the window on onsuccess event of Ajax.

```
success: function(g) {
  window.close(); OR $('#popup_id').hide();
  $('#div_id').html("Write message or other response form your action").
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue, onsuccess js is placed in the context of popup (since the form is there), `window.close()` closes the popup and the main window is still not focused

Comment: So the problem was that div that I want to update is in the main window and I can't access it from a popup js, but this question goes to another direction, something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264907/check-if-a-popup-window-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

In the associated action.js.erb file, add the following code.

```
function hideDialog() {
  var $dialog = $('#dialog_area');
  if ($dialog.is(':visible')) {  
    PageOverlay.hide();      
    $dialog.hide();
  }
  return this;
};
```