# check if a window has closed, inside of a iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

So i am building a 'like' button but i have a small problem after the user login's in through the little window, the user has to refresh the whole page. I want it to check if the window has closed and then refresh the iframe. So I have this code to open the pop-up and i've been looking at the at this post for help, but it's not helping that much.
       [Check if a popup window is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264907/check-if-a-popup-window-is-closed)

```
function grubber_highlight()
            {           
                    var popup = window.open("http://www.grubber.co.nz/login/", "newwindow", config="height=600,width=800, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no");
                        var windowloc = document.URL;
                        var windowlocation = (windowloc + "&highlight=t");
                        window.location = windowlocation;   
                        if (popup) {
                          popup.onclose = function () { alert("closed"); }
                        }                   
            }
```

I have this code to check if the window has closed and then alerts me that it has worked

```
                   if (popup) {
                        popup.onclose = function () { alert("closed"); }
                    }
```

The little window goes here 
     http://www.grubber.co.nz/login/ 
if anyone want's to know.

I also want it to be able to work on most browser newer that ie8

**edit**
   I googled a but deeper and found **onunload** it works on the closing but it also fires up when i open the window also...

**Question**

how to detect when the window is closed and then refresh the iframe

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Is your question "How do I replace the `alert("closed");` with some other code that refreshes an iframe?"

Comment: no how to detect when the little pop-up is closed

Comment: the code you posted shows that you *already* know how to detect when the little pop-up is closed. after all, you are running alert code when the pop-up is closed.

Comment: _"and then alerts me that it has worked"_ - You seem to be saying your code _already_ tells you when the popup closes.

Comment: @nnnnnn no that didn't work that was just someone's example that i was following, but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks guy's but i go the answer i wanted with the **onunload** event

```
     var popup = window.open("http://www.grubber.co.nz/login/", "newwindow", config="height=600,width=800, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no");
var windowloc = document.URL;
var windowlocation = (windowloc + "&highlight=t");
window.location = windowlocation;
var e = 0;  
if (popup) {
     popup.onunload = function () {
        if (e == 1)
        {
         //this will reload the iframe
        alert("closed");
         }
        else
        {
          //this will be when the pop-up gets created
        e++;                                    
        }                         
}
```

Comment: @Talha yer that was my example in the question, it didn't really help, but it did help me find the onunload event

Answer (score 2):

Supposed this is how the popup is opened:

```
win = window.open(...);
```

Then, you should repeatedly check if the popup is closed.

```
var timer, win;
function polling(){
 if (win && win.closed) {
   clearInterval(timer);
   alert('popup window is closed.');
 } 
}
timer = setInterval('polling()',100);
```

**UPDATED:**
Another technique is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264907/check-if-a-popup-window-is-closed)

Comment: sorry, i didn't think anyone was going to answer so i kind of went ahead with the onunload thing and got the answer

Comment: @Ryanc1256 if you find the answer, you can also share with us