# Opening the same pop up window it it's closed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For a reason, I have to use pop up window instead of modal window. I want the user do everything with the menu I provide inside the pop up window. Unfortunately, I can't disable the default close button (in the right top corner of the pop up window) and I don't want my user to use it.

After I googled it, I found it's impossible to make it disable, but in a forum (I forget the link) I found someone gave a trick to handle it: open the same pop up window when it's closed with that button. He didn't give sample code for it. How to do it? I don't know how to give function in that default close button. Please help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open When you open a window you get a handle to that window, which you can use to detect when its closed and re-open it. Warning: You will piss the snot out of people doing this.

Comment: See this question: [check if popup window is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264907/check-if-a-popup-window-is-closed)

Comment: Pop-up windows that won't close are good reason for me to stay off a site. Whatever your reason, I doubt it can be good enough to justify such a bad UX